# Dual boot from NVMe with HDDs in RAID-0

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, raid

I currently own a system with:

- ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming motherboard
- NVMe SSD as boot drive with Arch Linux and Windows 10 installed on it
- 1x SATA SSD with MAC OS X on it
- 2x SATA HDDs of the exact same model

I would like to set up the two HDDs in RAID-0 mode for more speed.

I set up the RAID in BIOS but unfortunately, when botting with Intel RST (RAID mode instead of AHCI), Linux can't won't boot as it is not able to detect any of the partitions on the boot drive.
Additionally, when using 'lsblk' through a Linux live USB, the NVMe device is not present. Switching back to AHCI (RST off) it is displayed but the HDDs work individually.

So my question is:
Can I set up RAID for the HDDs, while using the NVMe as boot device? If yes, how?
I don't really care if Mac will stop working (it will probably break due to iRST), as long as I can still use that SSD for something else.

Also, can I use partitions  with different filesystems on that RAID array? I want one for each OS.

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: You do understand, that with RAID-0 if any disk in the array fails, the entire RAID array fails?

Comment: @Attie Arch Linux

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. It's for non-sensitive data. Losing the HDD itself would be a much bigger problem than losing the data, which will be mostly just my movies / Steam / Spotify libraries which I can redownload at any time.